# Deciding on a software license for a C++ API

Tags: c++, licensing, api, gpl, bsd-license

I have designed and developed a C++ API. Its dependencies are:

- BLAS - custom license - http://www.netlib.org/blas/#_licensing
- LAPACK - modified BSD - http://www.netlib.org/lapack/LICENSE.txt
- GLPK - GPL

Mytonly restriction, besides being properly quoted as the author, is that I DO NOT want those who download it from my GitHub to be able to share the code among them; I want them to download it from my GitHub.

1. Based on my dependencies, can I do that?
2. If I can, which license would work?

Comment: Notice that the dependencies are: (1) For the BLAS and the LAPACK, I only include prototype of the function, but they are linked in build-time. The GLPK is only linked in build-time.

Comment: I am not sure you understand what "open source" means. You are using GitHub, after all, and you tagged this with multiple OSS license tags.

Comment: I don't think you can protect or limit an API. Think of your entire software, not of its interface (that is your API). An API can be followed &implemented by several software with different licenses (e.g. the POSIX API is implemented by Linux, FreeBSD, Solaris, ...)

Comment: BTW, what you want is very unclear, and probably impossible (at least with an open-source license, since by definition other people could improve your code). And you should improve your question by editing it, not comment it.

Answer (score 4):

As your API depends on a library that is licensed with the GPL license, the answer to your first question is: No, you can not apply those restrictions to your API.

The GPL is a copyleft open-source license. This means that any project that is based upon (or links to) GPL code must be made available under the same license (this is the copyleft nature of the GPL).
The fact that the GPL is open-source means that everyone has the right to make changes to the software covered by an open-source license and distribute a modified or unmodified version of that software.

---

If your reason for wanting to restrict who can distribute your project is to prevent multiple incompatible versions from being distributed at the same time, then you might look to trademark protection.

If you register a trademark on the name of your API, then you have full control over who gets to distribute software with that name. This is independent of the copyright license that applies to the software.
If someone wants to fork your API without your permission, they will have to rename their version to avoid infringing on your trademark.